# Drag a subview outside the superview in OSX

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview

I need to perform an operation similar to what happen in the dock bar when you remove an application.
I have a list of subviews in a superview, but the superview has defined size. Now when I drag one of the subviews outside the superview, the superview clip the dragged view.

Is there a way to permit to a superview to avoid clipping content or to move a subview into the superview of its superview?

(To manage the drag I use mouseDown and mouseDragged method from the superview)

Answer (score 1):

You can drag the subview avoiding the clipping by setting the superview property clipToBounds to NO.   In this way, when you move the subview, it will move outside the superview without clipping.